# Laravel create or update without two queries

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to use one form for both creates and updates. Both actions save through this method:

```
public function store() {
    $data = Input::all();
    $data['company_id'] = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $validator = Validator::make($data, Feature::$rules);

    if($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    Feature::firstOrNew(['id' => Input::get('id')])->update($data);

    return Redirect::route('features.index');
}
```

How can I rewrite this line:

```
Feature::firstOrNew(['id' => Input::get('id')])->update($data);
```

So that it doesn't fetch the object from the database first? There's no need for that; I'm not doing anything with it. It should either issue a `INSERT` if `Input::get('id')` is set, or an `UPDATE` if it's not.

Comment: Food for thought: I think this being "hard" relates directly to many databases lacking the concept of an "upsert". It's inconsistent enough between databases for most ORMs to skip the functionality.

Comment: @fideloper It doesn't have to be done with an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` style query; we can branch on the PHP side. Although it would be more reliable to do on the database end, in case someone deletes the record in between when you start editing it and when you click save.

Comment: For sure, didn't mean to make it sound like that's not a way to go as well!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have all fields unguarded in your model, I think you can do it like this:

```
$feature = new Feature($data);
$feature->exists = Input::has('id');
$feature->save();
```

If you have some guarded fields, then you can unguard it first:

```
$feature = new Feature();
$feature->unguard();
$feature->fill($data);
$feature->exists = Input::has('id');
$feature->reguard();
$feature->save();
```

The `reguard()` call is not actually needed if you don't do anything else with the model.

Answer (score 33):

This is what I use:

```
Model::updateOrCreate(
   ['primary_key' => 8],
   ['field' => 'value', 'another_field' => 'another value']
);
```

The second parameter is an array of the data for the model you want to save.

Comment: it still makes 2 queries: 
```php
        if (! is_null($instance = $this->where($attributes)->first())) {
            return $instance;
        }

        return $this->model->newInstance($attributes);
```

Answer (score 6):

I used to have this problem and created an accepted [pull request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/3875) on Laravel which you can use. Try the code below. The method you will basically need is the `findOrNew`.

```
public function store($id=0)
{
    $user = User::findOrNew($id);
    $data = Input::all();

    if (!$user->validate($data)) {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($user->errors);
    }

    $user->fill($data);
    $user->save();
    return Redirect::to('/')->with('message','Record successfully saved!');
}
```

My model uses self validation but you can create your own validation like the one you have now.

Comment: You've ignored the entire premise of the question. `findOrNew` is one query, `save` is the other. There doesn't need to be two. I do like having the `$id` passed in as an argument though. Actually, `findOrNew` might be useful for merging my create/edit methods too..hrm.

Comment: Yes, you can merge your create/edit method into single post by `findOrNew` using `$id` as ref. if `$id` is `0` or `null` or model does not exists, it's `INSERT` else it's `UPDATE`. This makes your form and code reusable.

Comment: You're not following. `findOrNew` issues a `SELECT`. I'm saying we can skip the `SELECT`. there's no data in there that I need, everything is coming from the form.

Answer (score 5):

Find or New based on primary key **id**

```
$data = Input::all();
$user = User::findOrNew($id);  // if exist then update else insert
$user->name= $data['user_name'];
$user->save();
```

First or New based on non-primary key **single filed**

```
$user = User::firstOrNew(['field' => $data['value'] ]);
$user->name= $data['user_name'];
$user->save();
```

First or New based on non-primary key **multiple filed**

```
$user = User::firstOrNew([
                     'field1'=>$data['value1'],
                     'field2'=>$data['value2']
                     ]);
$user->name= $data['user_name'];
$user->save();
```

Comment: `findOrNew` + `save` is two queries. `firstOrNew` doesn't do an update.

Answer (score 2):

If you are following the resource router methodology of laravel, you should use a separate method named update to update your model, so the separation can be done by the framework. With this it is still possible to reuse your form.

If you really want to avoid a new method to update the model, you could rewrite it as follows:

```
public function store() {
    $model = Input::has('id')
        ? ModelClass::findOrFail(Input::get('id'))
        : new ModelClass;

    $inputData = Input::all();
    $validator = Validator::make($inputData, ModelClass::$rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }

    $model->fill($inputData);
    $model->save();

    return Redirect::route('modelclass.index');
}
```

Comment: That still issues a second query via `findOrFail` but I guess it's better to error than issue an update against nothing.

Comment: To avoid the second sql query, I think you have to use a raw query with an INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement, but so you would bypass the Eloquent ORM.

Comment: "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" is MySQL specific, for anyone wondering. That means using that ties you to a specific database type in code. For many, that might not matter, however it's worth considering before using.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
$data = Input::except('_token');
$newOrUpdate = Input::has('id') ? true : false;
$isSaved = with(new Feature)->newInstance($data, $newOrUpdate)->save();
```

If `$data` contains an `id/primary key` it'll be updated otherwise insert will be performed. In other words, for updating, you need to pass the `id/primary key` in the `$data/attributes` with other attributes and second argument in the `newInstance` method must be `true`.

If you pass `false/default` to `newInstance` method then it'll perform an insert but `$data` can't contain an `id/primary` key. You got the idea and these three lines of code should work. `$isSaved` will be a `Boolean` value, `true/false`.

### You may write the code using one line:

```
with(new Feature)->newInstance($data, array_key_exists('id', $data))->save();
```

If `$data` contains `id/primary key` then it'll be updated, otherwise an insert will be performed.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about that is that it's instantiating the Feature object twice. `newInstance` ought to be static, but it isn't. Maybe I'll create a helper method.