# $fillable and create() not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've just installed new laravel project. After that, I created new Model but when I use create() function, it just show me that my new rows has been duplicated.

This is my code:

```
protected $fillable = ['id', 'setting_name', 'expected_type', 'default_val', 'modified_val'];
    // protected $guarded = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
function test() {
    $input = ['setting_name' => 'Test',
                    'expected_type' => '123',
                    'default_val'=>'123',
                    'modified_val'=>'123'];
                    // dd($input);
//both next two lines do not working
Setting::create($input);
    return Setting::firstOrNew($input);
}
```

I checked the error :

```
"Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'setting_name' (SQL: insert into settings (updated_at, created_at) values (1474452834, 1474452834))"
```

What i did wrong ?

Comment: I believe the method you want to be using is `findOrNew` rather than `firstOrNew()` - see more on this here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23325732/1739852

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question, but findOrNew or firstOrNew is not the problem for me now. I want to insert into database.

Comment: if you tried firstOrCreate() instead of firstOrNew()..?

Comment: every single one. :'(

Comment: Please provide the original code blocks that is being executed by the controller or command and the model which has the fillable attributes.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, I realized that I created __constructor for my model, that why I could not create object normally.
I removed that constructor and it works well. :D

Answer (score 0):

The error says you're trying to insert row with `setting_name` which is already exists in a table and you have `unique` constraint for this column.

So, make sure you're inserting this row only once and there is no any other row with the same `setting_name` value.

Comment: It's duplicated because of the create() method get nothing from my $input then run the sql: `insert into settings (updated_at, created_at) values (1474452834, 1474452834)`. The setting_name was inserted by null value.

Comment: Well, the error says there is dublicate. BTW, did you put `$fillable` in you controller?

Comment: I mean the duplicate is not real problem but create() method does not receive $input